# Parse a json reply from a jquery result in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a simple search form which query an external server for result with jquery

```
$("#formsearch").on("submit", function (event) {
        // everything looks good!
        event.preventDefault();
        submitFormSearch();
});
function submitFormSearch(){
    // Initiate Variables With Form Content
    var searchinput = $("#searchinput").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://external-server/api/",
        headers: {"Authorization": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},
        data: "action=Search&query="+searchinput,
                success:function(json){
                    console.log(json);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url:'search_func.php',
                        data: "func=parse&json="+json,
                        success:function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            $('#risultato_ricerca').html(data);                         
                            }
                    });
                }
    });
}
```

The first GET ajax works properly and I get correct data but trying to send this json data to my php script in post I can't get data. 
This is the code in search_func.php

```
if(isset($_POST['func']) && !empty($_POST['func'])){
    switch($_POST['func']){
    case 'parse':
            parse($_POST['json']);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
} 
function parse($json) {
    $obj = json_decode($json,true);
    var_dump($obj);
}
```

... it displays NULL

Where I'm wrong ?

EDIT: 
**SOLVED**

changing:
`data: "func=parse&json="+json,` 
to: 
`data: { func: 'parse', json: JSON.stringify(json) },`

json code is correctly passed to search_func.php
Changed function parse in php file to:

```
function parse($json) {
    $data = json_decode(stripslashes($json),true); 
    print_r($data);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: what values does $json have?

Comment: $json in function get value from $_POST['json'] in  parse($_POST['json']);
$_POST['json'] get value in jquery in  data: "func=parse&json="+json, 

 console.log(json); displays 
`code`Object {status: "ok", format: "json", query: "acquari", sort_by: "", sort_order: "desc"…}`code`

Comment: why do you need 2 ajax calls?

Comment: 1° to get search reply from external server
2° to elaborate in php the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the javascript json variable correctly filled (i.e. what does your console show you?) Possible you must encode the json variable to a string before posting.

i.e: instead of `data: "func=parse&json="+json,` use `data: "func=parse&json="+JSON.stringify(json),`

Comment: in console I see all reply from 1° [https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/694351/rx50bg3ieqlbcrmuzrmk]
this is the reply: [https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/694359/afx04tmzzmqnncx4fdfl]

Comment: JSON.stringify partially solved the problem.... 
but now in search_func.php if I do `$data = json_decode($_POST['json'],true); 
print_r($data);`   print give me null

Comment: Try to dump `$_POST['json']` first. Is it populated or not? If it is, something goes wrong while decoding, which could be due to added slashes (depending on PHP settings). `stripslashes` before json_decode should fix this.

Comment: thank you !! 
$_POST['json'] was populated and stripslashes solved the problem !!!
I finally get my array :)

Answer (score 0):

See this: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

The correct syntax is: `data: { func: 'parse', json: my_json_here }`

If this doesn't works is probably that you have to encode the JSON to a string (see `JSON.stringify()`)

Comment: JSON.stringify partially solved the problem.... 
but now in search_func.php if I do `$data = json_decode($_POST['json'],true); 
print_r($data);`   print give me null